# AndEngine GLES 2 Animate Character

Tags: java, animation, flash, andengine, spritesheet

I want to animate my character in game. My graphic animator prepare for me three options.

1. Frame-by-frame by this is over 9MB for one animation. With TextureSpriter 4-5MB.
2. [Spriter](http://brashmonkey.com) but I can't find how to handle scml in GLES 2.
3. FLA/SWF and this is my best promissing option because size of swf with animation is 1,8 MB. But so far I google that flash is no longer supported in android and it's big issue to use it with AndEngine.

What's more I found this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56256/how-to-play-animations-gif-swf) maybe something is changed since '13.

So I guess I got only option 1. Am I wrong? What do you use to animate?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I cannot give you a definite answer, however I could bring some tips to the table.

1. What approach you go for can depend heavily on the quality standards and style you have chosen for your game. Blockbuster titles with a ultra high resolution, framerate and detail standards and with a photorealistic style will most likely be better of with more advanced/high-power engine capabilities than a retro pixelated 8-bit game.
2. I have previously made an animated GIF loader for Android (support for animated gif was lacking back in the day, but I think it is present now). Don't go there. It's slow, takes a lot of processing and limits the quality badly. I kept hitting memory limits that would shut my app down without warning. Ugly.
3. SWF/FLA - Don't go there. See GIF.
4. Use Flash as creative tool but export .PNG? We have a [game in the works called astrobabe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bT7XizI6Kk) (click link for video) where all the graphics are hand animated FBF in adobe flash (animator's tool of choice) and later exported to PNG sprite sheets that are loaded. The animations has limited number of frames and sizes to fit in the power of two texture sizes. We also split some textures up in many parts and animate them in code where this makes sense. 
   Our engine for this game is AndEngine (which I cannot recommend anyone to use). Luckily our animator is very technically skilled and manages to keep the sprite sizes within bounds. Loading is done natively with AndEngine, while all animation playback is handled in a thin layer of convenience and simplification we made ourselves on top of Andengine's horrible animation system. This works great, although keeping track of the files is a hassle.
5. There is native support for animating with PNGs in Android. You write some XML that pulls in the right frames at the right position and time to form sequences that can be played back. I have not tried this myself, but I am guessing its much better than the GIF/SWF approaches. The problem is how the formats will be handled by your animator. I am sure there are some export plugins out there that will help you shoehorn some FBF material into a hodgepodge of PNG + XML that works as valid Android resources.
6. There are a myriad of sprite animation libraries and game engines out there all with their own way of handlig and supporting assets in different ways and formats. My latest ventures have been in [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which so far have been awesome. It ha good documentation too. Here is an article on [sprite animation in libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation). And what is awesome about libgdx is that it supports 3d with full model loading capabilities as well, so there are probably ways for you to fake 2d through that. That will give you access to a lot of high-end creative tools in form of 3D software.
7. Good luck!